# npm run build failing on Vue 3 project using vite

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vite

I've got a weird error when trying to do **npm run build** on a Vue 3 project. It fails with:

```
[vite:esbuild] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'endsWith')
file: /home/simon/vue3/birch-farm/src/main.ts
error during build:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'endsWith')
    at file:///home/simon/vue3/birch-farm/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-e8f070e8.js:13301:30
```

Delving into the file and line I can see it is the following code causing the issue, but I'm stumped with what I can do or try:

```
function resolveReferencedTSConfigFiles(result) {
  const dir = require$$0$4.dirname(result.tsconfigFile);
  return result.tsconfig.references.map((ref) => {
    const refPath = ref.path.endsWith(".json") ? ref.path : require$$0$4.join(ref.path, "tsconfig.json");
    return resolve2posix(dir, refPath);
  });
}
```

My **ts.config** file is as follows:

```
{
  "files": [],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.node.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "esnext",
        "types": ["node"]
      }
    }    
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check third object of your "**references**" Array that is

```
{
      "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "esnext",
        "types": ["node"]
      }
    }
```

It doesn't contains **path** key there and that's making that cause what you can do is add some check if path exists on this key then continue the flow otherwise don't do anything.
Also we can use filter function

```
function resolveReferencedTSConfigFiles(result) {
  const dir = require$$0$4.dirname(result.tsconfigFile);
  return result.tsconfig.references.map((ref) => {
    const refPath = ref.path.endsWith(".json") ? ref.path : require$$0$4.join(ref.path, "tsconfig.json");
    return resolve2posix(dir, refPath);
  });
}
```

change it to

```
function resolveReferencedTSConfigFiles(result) {
  const dir = require$$0$4.dirname(result.tsconfigFile);
  return result.tsconfig.references.filter((ref)=>ref.path!=undefined).map((ref) => {
    const refPath = ref.path.endsWith(".json") ? ref.path : require$$0$4.join(ref.path, "tsconfig.json");
    return resolve2posix(dir, refPath);
  });
}
```